# Ghost / Heroku : impossible import from Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, heroku, ghost-blog

I'm trying to start using Ghost.

I deployed my blog on heroku, but there I can't use the import function, which works locally.

When I import the file I get from Wordpress, it says "Import succesfull", but no content is present on the admin page.

What can I do ?

Comment: Are you using the wordpress plugin for this? If so you might want to check/ask on their [support page](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/ghost)

Comment: The import is not really the problem, since it works locally. The main issue is heroku hosting I think. I thought the only problem about that was images, but now we can add import to the list.

Comment: Have you tried to contact Heroku?